# General Object Counting Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection, counting

I'm trying to make a general object counting algorithm using python and openCV (open to try other methods) however I can't seem to get a good count on a variety of objects and don't know how to accomodate for that

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zv0MA.jpg are some example test images.

This is for to speed up inventory counting of smaller objects.

**EDIT
This is my current code (simple blob detector)

```py
# Standard imports
import cv2
import numpy as np;

# Read image
im = cv2.imread("./images/screw_simple.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
im = cv2.resize(im, (1440, 880))

# Setup SimpleBlobDetector parameters.
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

# Change thresholds
params.minThreshold = 10 #10
params.maxThreshold = 200 #200

# Filter by Area.
params.filterByArea = True # True
params.minArea = 500 #1500

# Filter by Circularity
params.filterByCircularity = True #True
params.minCircularity = 0.1 #0.1

# Filter by Convexity
params.filterByConvexity = True #True
params.minConvexity = 0.0 #0.87

# Filter by Inertia
params.filterByInertia = True #True
params.minInertiaRatio = 0.0 #0.01

# Create a detector with the parameters
ver = (cv2.__version__).split('.')
if int(ver[0]) < 3:
    detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector(params)
else:
    detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

# Detect blobs.
keypoints = detector.detect(im)

# Draw detected blobs as red circles.
# cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS ensures
# the size of the circle corresponds to the size of blob
total_count = 0
for i in keypoints:
    total_count = total_count + 1


im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, np.array([]), (0, 0, 255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

# Show blobs
cv2.imshow("Keypoints", im_with_keypoints)
cv2.waitKey(0)

print(total_count)
```

Here are the results I'm getting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ggf8A.jpg

How can I improve this algorithm to get better detection for a general use case of objects without having to modify the parameters each time for each object?

Comment: Show your code + your current vs the expected outcome.

Answer (score 2):

> You can try with an OpenCV approach, you could use a
>   `SimpleBlobDetector`

Obviously this is a test image and the result I got is also not perfect, since there are a lot of hyperparameters to set. The hyperparameters make it pretty flexible, so it is a decent place to start from.

This is what the Detector does (see details [here](https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/)):

1. **Thresholding**: Convert the source images to several binary images by thresholding the source image with thresholds starting at minThreshold. These thresholds are incremented  by `thresholdStep` until `maxThreshold`. So the first threshold is `minThreshold`, the second is `minThreshold + thresholdStep`, the third is `minThreshold + 2 x thresholdStep`, and so on.
2. **Grouping**: In each binary image,  connected white pixels are grouped together.  Let’s call these binary blobs.
3. **Merging**: The centers of the binary blobs in the binary images are computed, and  blobs located closer than `minDistBetweenBlobs` are merged.
4. **Center & Radius Calculation**:  The centers and radii of the new merged blobs are computed and returned.

*Find the code bellow the image.*

[image: Output Image]

```
# Standard imports
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image
im = cv2.imread("petri.png", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# Setup SimpleBlobDetector parameters.
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

# Change thresholds
params.minThreshold = 0
params.maxThreshold = 255

# Set edge gradient
params.thresholdStep = 5

# Filter by Area.
params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = 10

# Set up the detector with default parameters.
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)

# Detect blobs.
keypoints = detector.detect(im)

# Draw detected blobs as red circles.
# cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS ensures the size of the circle corresponds to the size of blob
im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, np.array([]), (0, 0, 255),
                                      cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

# Show keypoints
cv2.imshow("Keypoints", im_with_keypoints)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation - Seems like I was already using the same algorithm for blob detection and was hoping to modify it to have more accurate detection for a wide set of objects without individual adjustment each time

Comment: @Jack see my second answer

Answer (score 0):

> For better readability I rather put this in a second answer: You could
>   use a segmentation approach e.g. [watershed algorithm](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html)

Any grayscale image can be viewed as a topographic surface where high intensity denotes peaks and hills while low intensity denotes valleys. You start filling every isolated valleys (local minima) with different colored water (labels). As the water rises, depending on the peaks (gradients) nearby, water from different valleys, obviously with different colors will start to merge. To avoid that, you build barriers in the locations where water merges. You continue the work of filling water and building barriers until all the peaks are under water. Then the barriers you created gives you the segmentation result. This is the "philosophy" behind the watershed.

[image: Original image]
[image: Segmented image]